# IBM Push Notifications Dashboard Throwing Internal Server Error PUSHD102E

Tags: push-notification, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

When attempting to access my Bluemix application's IBM Push Notifications service dashboard I am redirected to a blank white page and in my web console the request returns a 500 error with the following response:

```
Internal server error occurred. Please contact admin. (Internal error code: PUSHD102E)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is most likely to occur when using an instance of the IBM Push Notifications service that was created prior to October 5th. As of October 5th new instances of IBM Push Notifications are delivered with a unique application secret for the service which is used to secure the service and its functionality.

To confirm if your push instance is failing due to lacking an application secret please check your IBM Push Notification service credentials from your application dashboard.

[image: Example of credentials that cause the PUSHD102E error]

The above is an example of service credentials that will cause the PUSHD102E error. Note how the only two values in the `credentials` array are `url` and `admin_url`. Compare that to the following which is an example of a push instance created after October 5th for the same application. Note the `appSecret` value now added to the `credentials` array.

[image: Example of credentials that work]

If you are indeed missing the appSecret value in your IBM Push Notifications credentials you will simply need to delete or unbind the service (done through the small light grey gear in the top right of the two images), and then obtain a new IBM Push Notifications instance through the `ADD A SERVICE OR API` button on the application dashboard.

Please note that you will need to reconfigure your IBM Push Notifications service and re-add your APNS certificates and/or GCM credentials upon adding the new instance.